# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Stylesheet.create') in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm

I am making a project in react native and I have installed all the dependencies for it but when I run the code it shows

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Stylesheet.create')
```

along with this underneath

> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:148:8 in
>   registerError
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:59:8 in
>   errorImpl
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
> - node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
> - node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
> - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
> - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
> - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
> - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
> - node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
> - node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13
>   in tryCallOne
> - node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6
>   in __callImmediates
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6
>   in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10
>   in __guard
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4
>   in flushedQueue
>
> - [native code]:null in flushedQueue
> - [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

at first it said something about one of the functions which I fixed but I don't understand where it is referencing the undefined object, if anyone can find what file or function it is talking about, that would be great.

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of the code rather than the error?

Comment: One reason could be you have typed Stylesheet instead of StyleSheet

Comment: evolution box   I think this is what you mean I do not know exactly what minimal reproducible example is but I think this is it. I have this same on 6 of my 7 files so judging from the last error was from one of these files I think it may be in here.                 const Explore = () => {
    return(
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 48 }}>hello </Text>
    )
};

const styles = Stylesheet.create({});

Comment: Gurupsan Giritharan ok i will check that, thanks for looking pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  _container: { 
    flex: 1, 
    backgroundColor: 'blue', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center' 
  }, 
  get container() { 
    return this._container; 
  }, 
  set container(value) { 
    this._container = value; 
  }, 
});
```